# public structure not recognised outside of its class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Gooday everyone.
1) I defined a public structure inside a class file (Films.cs) , like this:

```
public struct CategoryDetails
        {
            ...
        }
```

The class is NOT put into a namespace, for all that matters.

2) I have an aspx file called Catalog, with a code-behind file.
In the code-behind file, I have this (at the same level as the Page_Load method):

```
private void PopulateControls()
        {
            --> here I would like to have visibility to the CategoryDetails structure, which I don't
        }
```

I specify that the Catalog.ascx.cs (code-behind) file has a namespace.

- A. What I tried so far was to place the Films class inside the same
  namespace. No luck.
- B. As you can see, the structure is public. Thank you for your help.
  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Films.CategoryDetails` instead.  Nested classes/structs need to have their wrapping class prefixed (like a namespace) when accessed.  (unless you're accessing it from within that wrapping class)

```
private void PopulateControls()
{
    var categorydetails = new Films.CategoryDetails();
    //do stuff
}
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify, from within the `Films` class, you no longer need to prefix it.  (you still may prefix it if there are ambiguous naming issues):

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Films
    {
        public struct CategoryDetails
        {
        }


        public void DoStuff()
        {
            //both are valid
            var categorydetails = new CategoryDetails();
            var otherdetails = new Films.CategoryDetails();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This place is marvellous. Thank you, Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Are you implement struct inside class Films or inside class file films.cs (in global scope). Try navigate your struct like this

```
var categorydetails = new global::CategoryDetails();
```

Comment: The structure resides inside the public class Films (not the Films class file). Your suggestion, if I well understand, applies to the second situation. I will remember this for such cases. Thank you, Hamlet.